# How to retrieve intermediate CSV files from Google BigQuery YouTube transfer jobs

Tags: google-bigquery, youtube-data-api

In my current project, we use the standardized Transfer jobs in Google BigQuery to pull data from YouTube. And then from BQ to our SQL environment. This saves us the work maintaining the YouTube API extraction ourselves.

The issue is that these transfer jobs aren't stable. After consultation with Google Cloud Support, we postponed the schedule, they added multiple retries.

That solves some issues, the latest error messages suggest the YouTube API gave an invalid (or unexpected at the least) response format:

```
Error code 9 : Field claim_status is unknown.; Failed in processing schema for gs://bq-connectors-prod-youtube-data-jurisdiction_eu/projects/.../claim_report_XYX.csv
```

At another day, we see a similar error, but on field `reference_id`.

My question is:

Where in BigQuery can I see/ find/ retrieve the actual CSV file listed in the error message so I can verify the file layout. So I can communicate that back to Google support.

Comment: as you can see from error message it is not in BigQuery but rather in Cloud Storage.

Comment: Hi Mikhail,
I'm quite new to BQ, so I didn't see the distinction. Do I understand it correctly that BQ threw an exception due to an unexpected format delivered to the Cloud Storage bucket?

Comment: see the answer by @jinjun - that is exactly what I meant in my comment above :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gs://.../claim_report_XYX.csv" means the CSV file is in the Cloud Storage bucket, not in BigQuery. You should be able to locate that file in the bucket indicated by that gs:// path.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the clarification. I was unable to locate the exact file, but did find the storage explorer. So should the error re-occur, I know where to look.